# Entire family was lost because they were encoded onto media that was too small to hold them, to save some money

Tags: story-identification

I remember the technician whose job it was to reconstitute people complaining that because someone decided to save a little money an entire family was lost.  I think the people were emigrating to a different planet or something.  The family may have been the ones that had to pay to be encoded, they couldn't afford more storage, and were told it would be good enough (salesman just wanted their money, didn't care if they actually made it).

I think this was either a short story or a short scene in a larger work, not the main plot.  I have no idea what media it was or when I saw it.  Very unlikely to be a comic book, video game, or animated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  No idea at all when you read this?  Can you at least narrow it down to pre- or post-2000?

Comment: Do you really have no idea _at all_ when you read this? An upper and lower bound, even if they're decades apart, would be better than nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how this helps, but I was born in 1977.  So I guess I saw/read it sometime between when I was old enough to do so and last year.  I'm pretty sure it wasn't this year, but I've read lots of older SF&F so it really could have been written anytime.  Sorry, my memory is not the best.